# Weird b'\x' data while communication between avr and python serially

Tags: python, c, avr, pyserial, usart

I'm trying to send and receive data between python and atmega128 avr c script. I am getting weird type of byte I don't understand.

I've tried to read data in python code but the results look kind of like b'\x00' b'\x06' b'\x9e' b'f' b'\x06'. What is wrong in my code?

Here is my main thread of atmega

```
unsigned char Message[]="Initialization Complete!"; 
unsigned char buff = 0;

MCU_init(); 
UART_init_with_INT();

uart_send_string(Message,25);
uart_send_byte('\n');
uart_send_byte('\r');

return 0;
```

This is my python script reading data

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200)

while(True):
    print(ser.read())

#ser.write(b'hello test')
ser.close()
```

This is my actual weird result

```
b'\x86'
b'\x98'
b'\xf8'
b'\x9e'
b'\x86'
b'\x9e'
b'`'
b'f'
b'\x9e'
b'\x06'
b'\x06'
b'\x9e'
b'\x86'
b'\x9e'
b'\x98'
b'f'
b'\x06'
b'~'
b'\x86'
b'\x9e'
b'\xfe'
b'\x9e'
b'\xf8'
b'\x9e'
b'\x00'
b'\x98'
b'\x80'
b'\xe6'
b'\x9e'
b'\xe6'
b'\x9e'
b'\x00'
b'\x06'
b'\x9e'
b'f'
b'\x06'
b'~'
b'f'
b'f'
b'\x18'
b'\x06'
b'\xe6'
b'\x80'
```

However what I expect the output to be is
`"Initialization Complete!"`

P.S. This is UART implementation

```
void uart_send_byte(unsigned char byte)
{
        while(!(UCSR1A&(1<<UDRE1)));
        UDR1 = byte;
}

void uart_send_string(unsigned char *str, unsigned char len)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
                if(!(*(str+i)))
                        break;
                uart_send_byte(*(str+i));
        }
}
```

Comment: notice: you send `\n\r` instead of `\r\n`. is this intentional?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Nope mistake. I just switched to `\r\n` but result is still weird. Have any idea?

Comment: Why is this weird? What are you expecting different?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am expecting output "Initialization Complete!"

Comment: Maybe your port setup is incorrect.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks! I changed Baudrate to 57600 as avr UART Library is set as. And I get almost correct result 'Ini\xf4ialization Com\xf0lete!\n'. However any idea why there are '\xf4' and '\xf0' in the middle of result?

Comment: Did you write `uart_send_string`? If so, could you show implementation? If not, could you link to docs?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I appended to my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I solved.

I changed my python code as below and done! I had to setup port.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/COM4',
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

while(True):
    print(ser.readline())

ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What python is reading are bytes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

If you want to convert bytes to ascii you can do it with the following function:

```
ser.read().decode("ascii")
```

Depending on the encoding, the argument might change (e.g. could be utf-8)

Comment: This gives me error UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: In Python 3.x if you attempt to `print()` a `bytes` object, you'll get its `repr` instead, which will be a `b`-prefixed bytestring literal (using `\x` escapes). That looks like exactly what the OP is getting.

Comment: @Daniel. That is not quite true. Every character that is ASCII printable will be displayed as a character rather than a hex code.  You can see this with `\``, `f`, and `~` in the original output. The fact that the bytes aren't being printed as characters pretty much means they aren't ASCII